# Intellij IDEA - searching in jars - I require decompilation

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to search some phrase not only in project files ?
I mean: I choose some jar, and  force `Intellij` to search in this and decompilate if it is needed.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, if you have the sources of the libraries as jars or in zip files (libraries from JDK).

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> , type in the string to search and select the option below:

[image]

[image]

Obtaining the sources is very easy if you're using maven. My example shows the searchfor the constructor of the class `HttpGet` in Apache HttpClient.

Comment: I will try it later. I am using maven